# How to remove some decimal points in a list?

Tags: python, list, methods, decimal

I have a list like this:

```
my_list = [1.41421350951, 1.73205688772, 2.44948973178, 2.236067979]
```

I want to remove some decimals from each index by my own choice. for example, I want every index has just 4 decimals.

like this:

```
my_new_list = [1.4142, 1.7320, 2.4494, 2.2360]
```

what library or function or method should I use?

Comment: language are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the built-in function `round` with a list comprehension:

```
my_list = [1.41421350951, 1.73205688772, 2.44948973178, 2.236067979]
[round(e, 4) for e in my_list]
```

output:

```
[1.4142, 1.7321, 2.4495, 2.2361]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer dear kederrac. I am not playing with python. I am new in programming and I am just learning.

Comment: but is the python language? and welcome to programming, we also say `playing` when we want to learn things

Comment: Thanks dear kederrac. Yes, I am learning Python as my first experience in programming. It's challenging but enjoyable. I didn't know "playing" means "learning" in programming community ! So that's right. I am playing with python :-D